# Flutter autocomplete on paged data

Tags: flutter, autocomplete, pagination

In Flutter, what is the best way to do search and autocomplete on paged data?

I have a scenario, where a service is providing paged data for example `List<Hospital>`. Also, I have a `textfield` which needs to be autocomplete and show suggestions from the data that has been sent by the above service.

> Note: The service get paged data from the sqlite database.

For the autocomplete field, I'm using this package https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_typeahead

I have the service working fine, it sends paged data if I send the `pageIndex` and `pageSize`. But I'm not sure how to implement the autocomplete part, is there a way to implement this using `PageWiseLoad` and `type_ahead` package?

Comment: as far as i can understand u want to text search over a sql data. you need full text search funcationality and API where u can send some text and u can get similar suggestions.